# Fortran pointer error: "Invalid character in name "

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

I have a file called `m_mixing.F90`.

Inside this file, there's a function which is giving a compile error:

```
function getstackval(mix,sidx,hidx) result(d1)
    type(tMixer), intent(in) :: mix
    integer, intent(in) :: sidx
    integer, intent(in), optional :: hidx

    real(dp), pointer, contiguous :: d1(:)   !!This line is causing problems!

    type(dData1D), pointer :: dD1

    if ( present(hidx) ) then
       dD1 => get_pointer(mix%stack(sidx),hidx)
    else
       dD1 => get_pointer(mix%stack(sidx), &
            n_items(mix%stack(sidx)))
    end if

    d1 => val(dD1)

  end function getstackval
```

I compile as follows:

`mpiifort -c -g -DMPI -DFC_HAVE_FLUSH -DFC_HAVE_ABORT m_mixing.F90`

Here is the error:

> /opt/apps/siesta/siesta-trunk-r561/Src/m_mixing.F90:2533.13:
>
> real(dp), pointer, contiguous :: d1(:)
>
> .............1
>
> 1 Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

It doesn't seem to like the "pointer" key word?

Can anyone give me some tips? I'm a Fortran novice.

Comment: Can you trying using `real(kind=dp),.....` instead?

Comment: Character 13 appears to be the comma.  Make sure that comma is just a normal comma and not some weird comma-like non-ascii character.  Check other characters in the area too.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you remove the `contiguous` attribute on `d1`?

Comment: It goes away when I remove the "contiguous" keyword! But what have I just done?

Comment: It seems the compiler doesn't like the `contiguous` attribute for the function result, and it just hasn't a nice error message for that.  Which version of ifort are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@francescalus is right. Your version of ifort doesn't support the perfectly legal`contiguous` attribute for function results yet. For any new Fortraners out there, the `contiguous` attribute was introduced in Fortran 2008 for array pointers and assumed-shape dummy arrays. Examples of non-contiguous arrays are:

```
foo(::2) ! odd-numbered elements
bar%re   ! real part of a complex array
```

Telling the compiler that an array is contiguous simplifies memory traversal and element address calculations, potentially improving performance.

Contiguity can be tested with the inquiry function `is_contiguous(x)` where `x` is an array of any type. This returns a default logical scalar
with the value `.true.` if `x` is contiguous and `.false.` otherwise. If `x` is a pointer, it must be associated with a target.

Arrays in the C-language are always contiguous, so `c_loc` in `ISO_C_binding` was not permitted in Fortran 2003 for an array pointer or assumed-shape array. In Fortran 2008+, `c_loc` is permitted for any target that is contiguous (at execution time). For array pointers, the `contiguous` attribute has a runtime requirement that it be associated only with a contiguous `target` (via pointer assignment).

```
ptr => some_target
```

However, it is the programmer’s responsibility to ensure that the pointer will never become associated with a non-contiguous section; hence, checking `is_continuous(ptr)` after each pointer assignment is a must.